# Why isn't PInvoke crashing in case of violated calling convention (in .NET 3.5)?

Tags: .net, pinvoke, calling-convention, stdcall, cdecl

My solution has an unmanaged C++ DLL, which exports a function, and a managed application that PInvokes this function.

I've just converted the solution from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0 and got this PInvokeStackImbalance *"A call to PInvoke function [...] has unbalanced the stack"* exception. As it turned out, I was calling __cdecl'ed function, as it was __stdcall:

C++ part (callee):

```
__declspec(dllexport) double TestFunction(int param1, int param2); // by default is __cdecl
```

C# part (caller):

```
[DllImport("TestLib.dll")] // by default is CallingConvention.StdCall
private static extern double TestFunction(int param1, int param2);
```

So, I've fixed the bug, but now I'm interested in how did this work in .NET 3.5? Why the (many times repeated) situation when nobody (neither callee, nor caller) cleans the stack, did not caused stack overflow or some other misbehavior, but just worked OK? Is there some sort of a check in PInvoke, like mentioned by Raymond Chen in his [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx)?
It's also interesting, why the opposite type of breaking convention (having __stdcall callee be PInvoked like being __cdecl) is not working at all, causing just EntryPointNotFoundException.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some investigation:

The helper, that saves the situation from crashing, is another register - EBP, base pointer that points to the beginning of stack frame. All access to function's local variables is done through this pointer (except for optimized code, see the edit below). Before the function returns, the stack pointer is reset to the base pointer's value.

Before a function (say PInvoke) calls another function (imported DLL's function), the stack pointer points to the end of the caller function's local variables. Then the caller pushes parameters to the stack and calls that other function.

In the described situation, when a function calls another function as being __stdcall, while it is actually __cdecl, nobody clears the stack from these parameters. So, after return from the callee, the stack pointer points to the end of the pushed parameters block. It is like the caller function (PInvoke) just got several more local variables.

Since access to the caller's local variables is done through the base pointer, it does not break anything. The only bad thing that may happen, is if the callee function will be called many times at once. In this case the stack will grow and may overflow. But since PInvoke calls the DLL's function only once, and then returns, the stack pointer just resets to the base pointer, and all is well.
**Edit:** As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5358339/23715), the code may also be optimized to store local variables in CPU registers only. In this case EBP is not used and thus invalid ESP may cause returning to invalid address.

Comment: The "only bad thing that can happen" formulation is quite optimistic from today's perspective.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358107/why-does-a-net-program-survive-a-corrupt-stack-when-using-the-wrong-calling-c?rq=1) for another bad scenario (all local variables in registers, EBP leaves the scene altogether).  .NET 3.5 still corrects this for you (at the expense of performance), but .NET 4, by default, does not, and you'll crash.

Answer (score 7):

PInvokeStackImbalance is not an exception.  It is an MDA warning, implemented by a Managed Debugging Assistant.  Having that MDA active is optional, you can configure that from the Debug + Exceptions dialog.  It will never be active when you run without a debugger.

Getting the stack imbalanced can cause pretty nasty problems, ranging from strange data corruption to getting SOE or AVE.  Very hard to diagnose too.  But it can also cause no trouble at all, the stack pointer gets restored when the method returns.

Code compiled to 64-bit tends to be resilient, a lot more of the function arguments get passed through registers instead of the stack.  It will fail when forced to run on x86, the new default for VS2010.

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that the reason this changed between 3.5 and 4 is that the default behaviour for PInvoke changed. In 3.5 and earlier it checked for such things as Alex described and fixes them. This causes some overhead as the check needs to be performed on every PInvoke call. In .NET 4 the behaviour changed to *not* do this check to remove the performance hit on correct calls. Instead, the MDA warning was added.

The old behaviour can be re-enabled with the NetFx40_PInvokeStackResilience app.config setting (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff361650.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

When using the `DllImport`, the default is actual `WinApi`, not `StdCall`. WinApi isn't actually a convention, but represents the default convention of the system. Perhaps its possible that in .Net 3.5 WinApi represented _cdecl, while now it represents __stdcall

I really don't think that is the case, though, since I remember always having to specify __stdcall (or rather, WINAPI) when using P/Invoke. I'm not really sure why it worked in .Net 3.5. (Maybe DllImport was lazy back then, and just "overlooked" the calling convention - that would be weird)

Comment: Yep, I should have been more specific, that my app runs on Windows, where WinApi means StdCall.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, it seems like PInvoking CDecl function as StdCall is 'safe'. It is the additional MDA check, they've added in .NET 4.0, that makes the app fail.